# VSCode Breakpoints don't bind for Node application

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

This is my `lauch.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "/home/lucas/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.10/bin/node",
            "restart": true,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--inspect-brk",
                "./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js",
                "serve"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "trace": true,           
        }
    ]
}
```

The server starts fine, this is what I see in the terminal:

```
~/codes/my_code $
cd /home/lucas/codes/my_code ; /usr/bin/env 'NODE_OPTIONS=--require /home/lucas/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug-nightly-2022.5.3017/src/bootloader.bundle.js --inspect-publish-uid=http' 'VSCODE_INSPECTOR_OPTIONS={"inspectorIpc":"/tmp/node-cdp.517154-5.sock","deferredMode":false,"waitForDebugger":"","execPath":"/home/lucas/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.10/bin/node","onlyEntrypoint":false,"verbose":true,"autoAttachMode":"always","fileCallback":"/tmp/node-debug-callback-b4e1d5046671c261"}' /home/lucas/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.10/bin/node ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js serve 
runtime.launch Bootloader imported {
  env: {
    inspectorIpc: '/tmp/node-cdp.517154-5.sock',
    deferredMode: false,
    waitForDebugger: '',
    execPath: '/home/lucas/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.10/bin/node',
    onlyEntrypoint: false,
    verbose: true,
    autoAttachMode: 'always',
    fileCallback: '/tmp/node-debug-callback-b4e1d5046671c261'
  },
  args: [
    '/home/lucas/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.10/bin/node',
    '/home/lucas/codes/my_code/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js',
    'serve'
  ]
}
runtime Set debug mode { mode: 0 }
Debugger attached.
♥

  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:9982/ 
  - Network: http://192.168.200.18:9982/
```

However, the breakpoints that I've set are turned into gray.
So I type `Ctrl + Shift + P`, look for "Debug Diagnostics", and choose the option "Why my breakpoints don't bind".

It shows that my breakpoint was set to:

```
/home/lucas/codes/my_code//home/lucas/codes/my_code/src/index.js:17:1
```

Clearly, there is something wrong with this path..

I tried to include this:

```
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "/source/*": "${workspaceFolder}/*"
            },
```

and this:

```
            "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "!**/node_modules/**"
            ]
```

to `lauch.json`, but it didn't changed nothing.

**Is this a VSCode bug, or some wrong configuration I'm using?**